# import a sqlite dump file to webkit - phonegap approach

Tags: android, ios, webkit, cordova

I have a situation where in the sqlite db is generated using FIrefox's SqliteManager tool and it has to be imported into the webkit. I have exported the complete DB into .sql file with all create, insert query statements with SQLITEManager tool to a file in my HDD, that is as a .sql file.

Is there any libraries for importing this .sql file into the webkit?, but i only see a way where in i write a one time parser which will parse the .sql file and execute every command on to the webkit's DB, during first time initialization.

If there are any other better approaches, please advice and help.

Comment: Right now, the only way seems to be to add data via code. Have a single javascript file which does an insert only once.